# Use SwiftyJSON to get proper data

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swifty-json

This is my JSON data, how can I get src data in 0 in pickArray?

```
"pickArray" : "{\"0\":{\"src\":\"https:\/\/fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net\/h-ak-xpl1\/v\/t1.0-9\/p720x720\/18010403_1525007564199498_8009700960533638318_n.png?oh=25dbc9c1522dcfdd1d15cdd3e8c0c7da&oe=59997685&__gda__=1502470695_f212ade003e9b1c4ddc6a3ab6cc9e7e7\",\"width\":720,\"height\":720}}"
```

If I do it like this:

```
let dataArray  = json["pickArray"]
print("dataArray = ",dataArray)

dataArray =  {"0":{"src":"https://fb-s-d-a.akamaihd.net/h-ak-xpl1/v/t1.0-9/p720x720/18010403_1525007564199498_8009700960533638318_n.png?oh=25dbc9c1522dcfdd1d15cdd3e8c0c7da&oe=59997685&__gda__=1502470695_f212ade003e9b1c4ddc6a3ab6cc9e7e7","width":720,"height":720}}
```

But if I do it like this, show null:

```
let srcArray  = dataArray["0"]
print("srcArray = ",srcArray)
```

I'm using `swift3.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looks like that with key `pickArray` you are having `JSON` response in `String` so get that string and convert it data and get `JSON` from it and then get `src` from it.

```
let stringResponse  = json["pickArray"].stringValue
if let data = stringResponse.data(using: .utf8) {
     let pickArray = JSON(data: data)
     //Now access the pickArray to get the src
     var sortedKeys = [String]()
     if let allKeys = pickArray.dictionaryObject {
         sortedKeys = Array(allKeys.keys).sorted { $0.compare($1, options: .numeric) == .orderedAscending }
     }
     for key in sortedKeys {
         print(pickArray[key]["src"].stringValue)
         print(pickArray[key]["width"].intValue)
         print(pickArray[key]["height"].intValue)
     }
}
```

Comment: You have essentially copied my answer.

Comment: @TristanBeaton I haven't look your answer from that post when I comment on that post first after that I found this post answer here and when goes on that post I have marked as duplicate also your answer and my answer are both difference because you are thinking that whole JSON response is string and that is not the case

Comment: @TristanBeaton Also if you think question is duplicate mark as duplicate instead of posting same answer again

Comment: I modified mine after his response of it not working.

Comment: @TristanBeaton I'm saying this last time I haven't copied your answer, What you are suggesting is **whole `JSON` response is string**, What I'm suggesting is value of key `pickArray` is `JSON` string not whole `JSON` there is **big difference between them**

Comment: That is fine. What I got from his question was that his JSON was formatted incorrectly, so I fixed it so his whole string was JSON. It was just missing an opening and closing curly brace.

Comment: @TristanBeaton Thats what you think, Lets wait for OP response and check who is correct :)

Comment: I do understand how you got your answer now. I think yours is correct for this question.

Comment: @TristanBeaton Glad you understand it

Comment: @john Welcome mate :)

Comment: one last question! if i use "let pickArrays = try! JSON(data: data)" order is chainging not sequential do you know how to make sequence? @NiravD

Comment: @NiravD not sequence you know other way or make sequence again?

Comment: @john You mean you want order for you keys like 0,1,2,... ? Is this you want?

Comment: @NiravD yeap! exactly!

Comment: @NiravD want to make sequence following by original json key 0,1.2 if i use ur recommendation it work perfect! but random sequence

Comment: @NiravD can you check the for loop again? it keeps showing error in my xcode :( sorry for bothering you!

Comment: @NiravD damn!!!!!!!! it perfectly working!!! thank you so much ur my hero~~~~~~~ !!!! awesome!!! im so happy right now :D

Comment: @john Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let srcArray  = dataArray["0"].dictionaryObject!
print("srcArray = \(srcArray)")
```

Now you can access element of "0" value as like below. Hope this work for you.

```
let jsonScr = JSON(srcArray)
let srcURL = jsonScr["scr"].stringValue
```

Comment: it shows fatal error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value